# How can you loop through a vector<string> while checking the next item, and potentially skipping it

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a program in C++. Whenever I run the program, and try to print something, it will throw an exception. My code is this (so far):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>  
#include <sstream>  
using namespace std;

vector<string> tokenmaker(string inst) {
    string out;
    stringstream instok(inst);
    vector<string> tokens;
    while (getline(instok, out, ' ')) {
        tokens.push_back(out);
    }
    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "interpreter." << endl;
    bool exit = false;
    while (not exit) {
        string inst;
        getline(cin,inst);
        if (inst == "exit") {
            exit = true;
        } else {
            vector<string> tokens;
            tokens = tokenmaker(inst);
            if (tokens[1] == "print") {
                for (int i = 2; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
                    if (tokens[i+1] != "endl") {
                        cout << tokens[i] << endl;
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        cout << tokens[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF747D71706 in proglang.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000038. in xstring.cpp

That file is NOT in my project!

When I try to print `Hello world endl Hello world`, however, since then I have implemented a safeguard to prevent checking a vector item that does not exist.

Comment: Well when `i` is the last index of the vector `tokens[i+1]` would obviously be wrong, so, what do you want to do in that case?

Comment: The whole logic of how your printing handles `endl` doesn't make sense to me. If the _next_ token is _not_ `"endl"`, then you print the current token and a `std::endl` and then you skip the `"endl"`. How exactly is your code _supposed_ to print something like `"hello world endl what's going on"`? I would naively assume that you'd want `"hello world"` output on one line and `"what's going on"` on another but that's not at all what your code is doing even aside from the out of bounds access.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained better what you want to do. I got a clue from the title of your question but maybe explain that better in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (tokens[i+1] != "endl") {
```

with

```
if (i+1 < tokens.size() && tokens[i+1] != "endl") {
```

Your version has an out of bounds vector access when `i` is the last index of the vector.

Comment: A problem caused by your code can manifest later, where the most immediate line of code involved is some library code. For instance, if you attempt to access invalid memory (which you do, and which your error is telling you about), it's not always immediately apparent until the code that actually does something with it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @john's answer, where he correctly points out that you go out of bounds here,

```
                if (tokens[i+1] != "endl") {
```

you *also* have an out-of-bounds condition before that, here,

```
        if (tokens[1] == "print") {
```

because you are assuming there are at least two tokens (tokens[0] and tokens[1]). If you require a minimum number of tokens before you start parsing them then you can prevent your code from ever reaching that part. For example,

```
        vector<string> tokens;
        tokens = tokenmaker(inst);

        if (tokens.size() < someNumber) {
          std::cout << "need at least " << someNumber << " of tokens\n";
          continue;
        }
```

You can better catch these errors by using .at(), and using a try...catch block, as in

```
        vector<string> tokens;
        tokens = tokenmaker(inst);

        if (tokens.size() < someNumber) {
          std::cout << "need at least " << someNumber << " of tokens\n";
          continue;
        }

        try {
          if (tokens.at(1) == "print") {
          etc...
        }
        catch ( std::out_of_range & ) {
          std::cout << "out of range\n";
          return;
        }
```

But do still include @john's suggestion so that you don't go out of bounds in the first place. That's the belt; these are the suspenders. Wear both. ;)